# MySQLdb is caching SELECT results?

Tags: python, mysql-python

i'm running a SELECT query in a loop.

Once in a while, the database table is updated (by another program).

The first SELECT retrieves the correct data, but **further calls in the loop return the first values**.

How can I retrieve up-to-date data?

The only workaround I found so far, is reconnect to the DB on each iteration! In my example, uncommenting BOTH comment #1# and #2#. Uncommenting only #2# is not enough (i.e., cursor is recreated), the results are still cached.

Here's a working sample that gives the error.

```py
import MySQLdb
from time import sleep

class DB:
    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = MySQLdb.connect(mysql_host, mysql_user, mysql_pass, mysql_db)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

    def get(self):
            sql = ''' SELECT id, message FROM mps_messages
                      WHERE topic=%s ORDER BY id LIMIT 1  '''
            #1# self.connect()
            #2# self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
            self.cursor.execute(sql, ("topic",) )
            rec = self.cursor.fetchone()
            print rec

    def loop(self):
        while True:
            self.get()
            sleep(4)

db=DB()
db.loop()
```

- OS: ubuntu,
- python: 2.7.4
- mysqldb: 1.2.3
- mysql: 5.5.34

Answer (score 15, accepted):

i had to add

```
connection.autocommit(True)
```

Adding SQL_NO_CACHE had no effect on the presented case, apparently because there was no caching involved.

I still don't understand why a SELECT needs COMMIT.

I'll open a new question about it.

Comment: And where would you add this line? At the end of the loop?

Comment: baahh, 3 years ago. I think it is a connection parameter, or right after the connection

Comment: It was just before you "close" or end the while loop... And it worked thanks... Let me upvote

Comment: did you figure out why it requires autocommit? or any way of doing SELECT without autocommit?

Comment: This is very strange. I had the same issue and turning on autocommit solved it. Even while I was doing manual commits during the runtime (fetched rows were deleted, so I had to commit). This is very strange and not solved 3 years later.

Comment: You saved me from a huge amount of headaches, I was trying it for more that two hours. and me too, I still don't understand why a SELECT needs COMMIT. thanks

Comment: Just commenting to say that this is still seemingly the case in 2024. I had to turn on autocommit to prevent this caching behaviour on SELECT statements. Single commit after the statement doesn't work. The only thing I can imagine being wrong is maybe there is some dangling uncommitted transaction left over somewhere. But my app is tiny so far - there's almost no chance I wouldn't have found. Had to turn on autocommit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SELECT` with [`SQL_NO_CACHE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/query-cache-in-select.html) keyword:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE id, message 
FROM mps_messages
WHERE topic=%s 
ORDER BY id 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: it didn't affect the query in the loop. see my solution

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to consider is change the table to a non transactional storage engine like MyISAM, if using transactions on that particular table is not compuslory