# Why a COMMIT is needed before SELECT, for a previously commited UPDATE?

Tags: python, mysql

The situation is detailed in my previous question: 
[MySQLdb is caching SELECT results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23635130/mysqldb-is-caching-select-results/23683656#23683656)

In short:

1. python 2.7 + MySQLdb
2. the "issue" happens inside a Python script (but not from the mysql client prompt)
3. when querying a `SELECT` inside a loop, the first result is repeated for all subsequent iterations of the loop
4. this happens even though another program updates the DB (and commits).
5. I can see the changes from mysql clients, but not from my python loop.
6. `SQL_NO_CACHE` didn't fix it
7. recreating a cursor didn't help!
8. `autocommit(True)` worked --> each query reflects DB change.

So why MySQLdb thinks it's inside a transaction, when it's clearly irrelevant?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python's MySqlDB not getting updated row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617637/pythons-mysqldb-not-getting-updated-row)

Comment: It's all due to the default isolation level of MySQLdb. See the answer to previous SO question linked above.

Comment: This issue is that if it returned the result you're looking for it'd be a violation of your transaction, if the result doesn't exist in one transaction it can't appear later in the same transaction.

Comment: @scragar - i didn't ask for transactions. does any cursor in MySQLdb is a transaction?

Comment: @Berry Tsakala - Run `SHOW VARIABLES;` If autocommit is turned off every session you make will be in an implied transaction(and a new one started whenever you end it). That's the most likely cause of your problem.